# slayer exciter(tesla coil) circuit modification to allow better audio input

Tags: audio, oscillator, tesla-coil

So I have the circuit working with a kit but the only thing is the audio aux has this offset voltage or some high voltage output I suspect. So when I plug my phone to the tesla coil through the audio jack, there is strong interference. Can anyone offer a solution to the interference? The coil can sing fine, but this interference is really annoying making my phone glitch and I'm worried it might break it. My phone only glitch and the touchscreen becomes odd and non-responsive when the aux is plugged into my phone.
[image] 
Thanks

Comment: Your phone has multiple antennae for GMS, WiFi, GPS and Bluetooth. Are you not worried that you could damage your phone in such close proximity to an RF source?

Comment: "thing is the audio aux has this offset voltage or some high voltage output I suspect" I sense a strong XY problem. What did you measure to conclude it has offset or "high voltage output"?

Answer (score 1):

It's a miracle that your phone works near this device. The capacitive touchscreen is based on quite weak electric field between your finger and the sensors behind the glass. When the ground of your phone and the exciter are connected, the field from the exciter antenna probably wins the touchscreen sensing field. You can add a common mode filter and increase the distance. In theory you can also keep your hand and the phone in a transparent metallized plastic bag which is connected to the ground of your phone. Only offline content is available.